# Generating random numbers with Snow package in R

Tags: multithreading, r, random, snow

I'm currently running a program which is multithreaded via the snow package (using `clusterApplyLB`) and in the code I generate a random number, but it seems the threads are all using the same seed to generate this number so they give the same result.

Is there a way to have the different threads start with different seeds?

I can't just generate a random seed for each thread, because this would have the same problem, and I'm also not keen on the idea of having a new index argument for the seed in the function called by each thread (i.e. the function being called assigns 1:32 as seeds for each thread as this isn't really "random.")

Comment: Could you give a minimal code example where the problem occurs? For example let a few threads draw some random numbers and show that they all store the same result.

Comment: Perhaps this would help? http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/parallel/

Comment: @Aaron The `rlecuyer` package looks exactly what I was looking for, feel free to add it as an answer so I can accept. Otherwise I'll just throw it up there for anyone else looking for it.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.  Go ahead and answer yourself, thanks. I don't have time right now to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clusterSetupRNG` function in the snow package will set a different random number stream on each of the members of a cluster.  The `clusterSetRNGStream` function in the parallel package does the same thing.  Just call one of those functions before calling `clusterApplyLB` and everything should work fine.

You may also want to look at the harvestr package for another way to manage the multiple random number streams (in a way that focuses on making the whole process reproducible).